# How to save the state of button onced pressed

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I just fetch data & load it into `recyclerView` that can be set on `adapter`. It contains a button which is able to send data to `Firebase`.

> When I press the button its `color` and text changes as per requirement
>   but whenever I reload it again the default button state gets loaded.

So I want that button should save its state once clicked and whenever I reload the same activity it should be in the saved state.

```
      viewHolder.send_req.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(final View v) {
                final Integer taggedPosition =  viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                Log.d(TAG,"button click data:"+taggedPosition);


                firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(u_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.getResult().exists()){
                            name = task.getResult().getString("name");
                            userID = task.getResult().getString("user_id");

                    firebaseFirestore.collection("Pets").whereEqualTo("name",name_data).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            for (final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                                docID = documentSnapshot.getId();
                                Log.d(TAG,"selected pet doc id:"+docID);
                                if (docID!= null){
                                   final Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                                    final Map<String, Object> userMap1 = new HashMap<>();
                                    userMap.put("doc_id",docID);
                                    userMap.put("pet_id",pet_no);
                                    userMap.put("sender_id",userID);
                                    userMap.put("sender_name",name);
                                    userMap.put("pet_name",name_data);
                                    userMap.put("pet_profile",image_url);
                                    userMap.put("timestamp",FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                                    //do not place request if data is already exist in document
                                    firebaseFirestore.collection("Send_req").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                                             final Button send_req = (Button)v;
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                                    list.add(document.getString("doc_id"));
                                                    list.add(document.getString("sender_id"));
                                                }
                                                if (!(list.contains(docID)&& list.contains(userID))){
                                                    send_req.setClickable(true);
                                                    Toast.makeText(context,"send request successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    send_req.setText("Cancel Request");
                                                    send_req.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                                    String btnname =send_req.getText().toString();
                                                    String button_name = (String)userMap.put("btnName",btnname);
                                                    firebaseFirestore.collection("Send_req").add(userMap);
                                                    send_req.setClickable(false);


                                                }
                                                else {

                                                    if ((list.contains(docID)&& list.contains(userID))){
                                                    if(send_req.getText().toString().equals("Send Request") )
                                                    Toast.makeText(context,"you already send request",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    send_req.setText("Cancel Request");
                                                    send_req.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                                    send_req.setClickable(false);
                                                    notifyDataSetChanged();}
                                                  }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });


                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Save in `shared preferences`

Comment: `Shared preferences` would be there even if you restart the app and would require resetting it. I presume the easiest way would be having a `static boolean` in some convenient class.

Comment: can you please suggest me according to my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeClass {

public static boolean isFeatureSelected = false;
...
}
```

And you can always invoke it with `SomeClass.isFeatureSelected`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable such as:
`boolean isClicked = false;` and `int pos = -1;`
Then the first time you changed the button background change the boolean to `true` and `pos = position;`.

Then in the `onBindViewHolder` of your `RecyclerView` do this:

```
if(isClicked && position == pos){ // check the state of the button and the adapter position. 
    // change your background here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the pojo of the response then you can define a variable in the pojo and change the value on button click on that position. As define by [ChrisZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57201381/2196176).

But if as you don't have pojo I will suggest you to create a List of Boolean `size` same as the `recyclerView item size` with `false` value. Once you click on the button make the list boolean to `true` at that position so you can know on which position you already clicked and change the UI with the `bool` value at that position.